# SQL Change all rows with character value to null

Tags: sql

I have a column `phone` and I want all the record that have character value to change to `null`.

Comment: probably because of leading zeroes

Comment: And country specifics code area.

Answer (score 4):

```
UPDATE table SET phone = NULL WHERE phone LIKE '%[a-z]%'
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/12424

Comment: You'd have to create a `CLR` object to use regex in SQL - see here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlclr/archive/2005/06/29/regex.aspx

Comment: This actually works supprisingly, didn't think it would - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/12424

Answer (score 0):

This works in MySQL - set phone to NULL where phone contains at least one character:

```
UPDATE phone SET phone = null  WHERE phone REGEXP '[a-zA-Z]+'
```

Comment: The tag related is specifically `SQL`.

Comment: I see the description of 'SQL' tag now, didn't realize it

Answer (score 0):

Try Following:

```
UPDATE table SET phone = null  WHERE IsNumeric(phone)!=1
```

Try with `IsNumeric` function in SQL.